# Average Coordinate Points in R?

Tags: r, coordinates

I have a .csv of species occurrences with individual lat-long points, but I am trying to aggregate them all into a singular 'average' coordinate point per species. From some digging I see there can be issues with a simple average (high altitude or low altitude outliers can cause issues). Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this easily/quickly in R? Thanks

Data is seen up like this but I have 71,000+ occurrences total.

| species | longitude | latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abies amabilis | -111.112964 | 41.199112 |
| Abies arizonica | -110.8678 | 37.0349 |
| Abies bifolia | -111.650833 | 41.82 |
| Abies bifolia | -113.377722 | 41.950833 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, mean), species]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
your_data <- tibble::tribble(~species, ~longitude, ~latitude, "Abies amabilis", -111.112964, 41.199112, "Abies arizonica", -110.8678,  37.0349, "Abies bifolia", -111.650833,     41.82, "Abies bifolia", -113.377722, 41.950833)
```

you could do

```
aggregate(. ~ species, your_data, mean)
```

to calculate averages. This returns:

```
          species longitude latitude
1  Abies amabilis -111.1130 41.19911
2 Abies arizonica -110.8678 37.03490
3   Abies bifolia -112.5143 41.88542
```

Alternatively, `dplyr` could be used to do

```
library(dplyr)

your_data %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(across(.fns = mean))
```

which similarly returns

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  species         longitude latitude
  <chr>               <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Abies amabilis      -111.     41.2
2 Abies arizonica     -111.     37.0
3 Abies bifolia       -113.     41.9
```

Comment: rock on!! that worked, thanks for the help